# CakePHP and SSL

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, ssl, root

I just installed a SSL certificate on my website that uses CakePHP and now the site doesn't load anymore files from webroot (images, css files). Any ideas? I think SSL installation affected mod_rewrite, or something like this.

Comment: It should now affect anything like that (unless you have some special rewrite rules that playing with port numbers/protocols -- and even this is still quite unlikely to break the website). Remove .htaccess file completely and see if it still does not work. The best advice -- check Apache's access and error logs. With some info on hands it can be looked further. In any case -- technical questions like that should be asked on ServerFault.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I have several CakePHP sites with SSL certs and mixed content (some SSL, some not) that run perfectly well. My first thought would be that your security settings might be preventing this content from loading if it's not loaded via https. You didn't provide much info, though, so this is really just a shot in the dark.

Comment: I've installed the SSL cert automatic, on GoDaddy, so I don't have much info. I've just made a request on GoDaddy and the Certificate was installed. I use rewrite from point 3. http://book.cakephp.org/view/37/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this problem. Check your sites configuration for apache2. Make sure:

AllowOverride all

is set to allow .htaccess overrides under ssl. Here is my snippet of my config (on ubuntu).

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```