# CakePHP Force SSL - env('HTTPS') always null

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl, https, cakephp-1.3

I've tried quite a few different solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182260/cakephp-selective-ssl), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782281/cakephp-and-ssl), [here](http://techno-geeks.org/2009/03/using-the-security-component-in-cakephp-for-ssl/), [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/pr1001/2008/06/05/forcing-https-using-the-security-component)) but almost all of them caused either 404 or infinately loops.

Finally I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959585/cakephp-https-secure-payment-form) which seems to get the closest to working; but it also causes an error in Firefox when I try to load one of the actions I wish to require SSL on:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this  address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

Finally through a bunch of debugging I have found that `env('HTTPS')` always returns `null` for some reason (as does `$this->RequestHandler->isSsl();` and `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`) even when I'm using an HTTPS connection. I cannot understand why this is happening, since my browser reports that I am SSL secure and my certificate seems to be installed correctly.

### More Info

**nginx server**

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/domain.chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;
...
```

**App Controller**

```
var $secureItems = array('login', 'edit', 'viewDocs');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'display');
    $this->set('loggedUser', $this->Auth->user());

    $this->__checkSSL();
}
```

`__checkSSL()` and supporting functions are directly from the previously link question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959585/cakephp-https-secure-payment-form)).

Pages load fine in HTTP and HTTPS as long as its not one of the actions I have listed in `$secureItems` as soon as I go to one of those actions (either HTTP or HTTPS) it infinately redirects.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**:

I am pretty sure the issue is an infinite loop caused by `env('HTTPS')` always being null. Since its null the check condition is always false and makes it redirect to an HTTPS URL even though its already on one.

Is there another way I can check for HTTPS or can someone tell me why `env('HTTPS')` is always returning null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're edit is a step in the right direction...

It is down to the web server to set environment variables such as `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

If this has a no value, you need look no further than the web server - nginx in your case - or at any web servers inbetween (reverse proxies, etc.)

I don't have any experience with SSL on nginx in particular, but from what I can gather you need to make sure nginx is sending `fastcgi_param HTTPS on` for connections on port 443.

Adding something like this, perhaps:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

    # ...
}
```

Search for ["nginx fastcgi_param HTTPS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx%20fastcgi_param%20https&gws_rd=ssl) for other config examples.

I also found [some other variables](https://web.archive.org/web/20170131021400/http://claylo.com:80/post/7617674014/ssl-php-fpm-and-nginx) that may be of use further down the line.

Comment: Fantastic, I am using FastCGI but I did not set HTTPS on for this server, let me try this out.

Comment: Awesome, works great! This was definately the issue. I also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848438/fastcgi-application-behind-nginx-is-unable-to-detect-that-https-secure-connectio) just now which is the same thing, it also helped.